# Jquery How to disable the submit button after submit?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Nothing worked for me. i have using given form

```
<form method="post" id="mainform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype='multipart/form-data' ><div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-push-1">            
                        <div class="form-actions">
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-9">
                                  <div class="button-group"> 
         <button type="submit" class="btn blue ss"  id="mainbutton"> Submit <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>

         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </form>
```

and my Jquery is

```
<script>
$('#mainform').submit(function(){ 

  $("#mainbutton").attr("disabled", true);
```

});

Comment: Doesn't this `submit` cause a postback on the page

Comment: Normal submission will refresh the page... Do you want the button to be disabled after refreshing..?

Comment: The code you have posted behaves the way you have described: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8hbm5na/1/). Your problem is not reproducible. Side-note: You should probably be using `.prop()` here.

Comment: What are you doing to stop the form from being submitted, which is the default behavior? Your code works, however the page will reload itself, and all your jQuery changes lost, unless you prevent it from doing so.

Comment: Are you sure handler is bound to element???

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#mainbutton").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled','');
}
```